# I want the index of each user in Gatling rampUsers

Tags: scala, gatling

I have scenario I will run 10K times, and I would like each call to be different.

1. How do I write a feeder that will simply return the numbers from 1 to 10000? (i'm very new to scala)
2. Is there a way I can get some sort of index from rampUsers?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could do:

```
  def newSequence():Iterator[Map[String,String]] = {
    val seq: Iterator[Int] = Iterator.from(1)
    Iterator.continually(Map("id" -> seq.next()))
  }    

....

.feed(newSequence())
```

Comment: And if I want from..to? Can I do Iterator.from(1).to(10) ?

Comment: You can do everything, but feeder would probably not be the right place to control number of users. Unless you want to make it cyclic.

Comment: I want to identify each and every user. I just need a simple integer index, but I want to control the first and last number - so i can run it on 10 servers and have eventually 10K unique users. What do you suggest Gurov?

Comment: The best if you can use string identifiers with prefix or suffix unique for the load server. Otherwise you'll have to split the integer space between those.